# In Odoo What is "Application" field in Settings / Users / Groups / Create new

Tags: odoo-8

Go to Settings / Users / Groups / Create new

What is Application field for? I have installed Warehouse module and I got two basic groups (for example).

1. Warehouse (as an application) / Manager (Group Name)
2. Warehouse / UserWarehouse / UserWarehouse / User

Now here I can also assign a parent to an application.

My question is what is it actually and for what purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Application " field is for what module you are going to create group. So in your case the application will be Warehouse module but you need to list down those privilege and access level per python object and the menu will be provided to each group.